# solve easy problem with group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is a simple problem  which can  be  found  in  every  elementary group textbook:

$H,K$ are finite subgroups of group $G$, then
$$|HK|=\dfrac{|H|\cdot|K|}{|H\cap K|}$$

Could you help me to prove it with [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)? Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean "group action"? What group action and on what set(s)? The claim follows straightforward from the fact that $$h,h_1\in H\;,\;k,k_1\in K :\;\;\;hk=h_1k_1\iff h_1^{-1}h=k_1k^{-1}\in H\cap K\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks!  I seek a new proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that the group $H^{\text{op}} \times K$ (where $H^{\text{op}}$ denotes the group $H$ with reversed multiplication) acts transitively on the set $HK$ via multiplication - i.e. $x^{(h,k)} := hxk$ for $x \in HK$. The claim follows now from the orbit stabilizer theorem.

Comment: Maybe mention that the stabilizer of $x=1_G$ is easy to calculate. For a general $x$, it is probably a mess.